# Who decides titles for dubbed versions?

Tags: title, film-industry

As we know, many Hollywood movies are dubbed into non English versions. For example, [titles of *Star Wars: The Last Jedi*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/84868/48608) are given in different languages. In majority cases, the original title in English is changed into the language it is dubbed in order to suit the taste of the audience. There are other reasons also, e.g [*Thor: The Dark World*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/13508/48608).

Naturally, the movie directors, producers and screenplay writers do not have a command over all the languages the movie is dubbed. In these cases, who takes the responsibility of naming the movie in dubbed versions? Is it the distributor who buys the movie or the dialogue writer or someone else?

<sup>Just on a related note, this question is inspired after watching the names of some [English movies dubbed into Telugu](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-most-ridiculous-names-given-to-Hollywood-movies-in-Telugu) with funny names. The original movie names were totally changed.</sup>